# Laravel phpunit how to use diffent migrations for tests

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, database-migration

I am trying to set up tests in Laravel, but I want to run different migrations from those that usually run.

The migrations that I run to initiate the database imports data from a production environment.
For testing I want to use a different database called "test", and I want to fill this test database with test data, not production data.

I added a "testing" connection to `config/database.php` which uses the "test" database:

```php
'connections' => [

        'mysql' => [
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            ...
        ],

        'testing' => [
            'database' => 'test',
            ...
        ],
],
```

And I setup `phpunit.xml` to use this "testing" connection:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit ...>
    ...
    <php>
        <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="testing"/>
        ...
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

Now I want to initialize this "test" database with test data, using migrations from a different folder than the default.

I can use the normal migrations like this:

```php
<?php

namespace Tests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;

abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;

    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->seed();
    }
}
```

But this uses the default folder `database/migrations`.
I would like to put the testing migrations in folder `tests/database/migrations`.

Is there a way to let `use DatabaseMigrations;` use migrations from another folder?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might need to override `runDatabaseMigrations` method in `DatabaseMigrations` trait and set the app's database path from there before your migrations run.

The `runDatabaseMigrations` method might end up looking like this:

```
use DatabaseMigrations { runDatabaseMigrations as runMigration; }

    public function runDatabaseMigrations()
    {
        $this->app->useDatabasePath(base_path('tests/database')); //example path
//        dump($this->app->databasePath());
        $this->runMigration();
    }
```

Or you can set in the `boot` method of your AppService provider:

```
    if (config('app.env') === 'testing') { //Laravel automatically set env to 'testing' when running test
        $this->app->useDatabasePath(base_path('tests/database'));
    }
```

The migration will look for a sub-folder of 'tests/database' called "migrations".

> PS: There will be side effect to this if you're have some other code or folder in the default `database` folder. Example, your factory class there will not be found for this test class.

Comment: Two very elegant solutions, thank you. It took me a while to find out that the path in your code should be ```tests/database``` and not ```tests/database/migrations```. The migration will look for a sub-folder called "migrations".

Comment: Apologies for that, I didn't read the question very well to know you needed `tests/database` I will update the answer to reflect this and also include your statement "The migration will look for a sub-folder called "migrations""

Comment: I took the general service provider approach since I have huge legacy project for which I want to keep developing but with tests.

Turns out, with the newer class-based factories in Laravel 8 they work just fine in the test classes even though the path is overwritten since the factory classes are name-spaced and imported at the top of my test :) awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Artisan migrate has a path option, you have to make your own trait to have similar functionality. I'm thinking something like this.

```
trait PathDatabaseMigrations {

    public function runDatabaseMigrations()
    {
        // optimal 
        $path = 'tests/database/migrations';

        $this->artisan('migrate:fresh', ['--path' => $path,]);

        $this->app[Kernel::class]->setArtisan(null);

        $this->beforeApplicationDestroyed(function () {
            $this->artisan('migrate:rollback', ['--path' => $path,]);

            RefreshDatabaseState::$migrated = false;
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `RefreshDatabase` trait has a method called `migrateUsing` which will overload the parameters that it uses when running the migrations. I changed to a specific test migration file for a single test by passing it in as the `--path` parameter to the migration.

```php
namespace Tests\Unit;

use Tests\TestCase;
use App\Models\Traits\HasUuid;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class HasUuidTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    protected function migrateUsing()
    {
        return [
            '--path' => 'tests/migrations/2022_03_15_220516_create_test_uuid_table.php'
        ];
    }

    public function test_has_uuid()
    {
        $model = new TestUuid;
        $this->assertEmpty($model->id);
        $model->save();
        $this->assertNotEmpty($model->id);
    }
}

class TestUuid extends Model
{
    use HasUuid;
}
```